# When running ShellRunas.exe through my c++ program into explorer++ it does not take me to the correct folder

Tags: c++, windows, command-prompt

When this command:

```
C:/utils/ShellRunas.exe C:/utils/Explorer++/Explorer++.exe //foo/boo/test/review/Test/
```

is ran through the command prompt, it works perfectly.

However, when the command is executed through my program, it simply just opens up Explorer++ without accessing the proper folder.

`//foo/boo` is a file server, if that matters.

```
void planWrapper(void)
{
    const char* cmd = "C:/utils/ShellRunas.exe C:/utils/Explorer++/Explorer++.exe //foo/boo/test/review/Test/";
    runCommand(cmd);
}

bool runCommand(const char* cmd)
{
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The path separator on Windows is the backslash (`\\`), not the forward slash ( `/`).

Comment: @KenWhite That does not affect which directory is opening when explorer++ runs. I appreciate the suggestion however.